# On record creation Add Prefix with Id to a new column in SQL table using EF / EF Core 2

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have the following model

```
public class Student
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    private string reference;

    public string Reference
    {
        get
        {
            return this.reference;
        }
        set
        {
            this.reference = "ST" + Id;
        }
    }
}
```

and i am trying to write to the database Reference Column like

```
Id - Reference
1   - ST1
2   - ST2
```

My context class has the following configuration

```
public class SchoolContext : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Student> Student { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<Student>()
        .Property(b => b.Id)            
        .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();

        modelBuilder.Entity<Student>()
        .Property(b => b.Reference)
        .HasComputedColumnSql("[Id]")
        .ValueGeneratedOnAdd();
    }
}
```

But i am not getting what i am trying to. **Please bear in mind i dont want to generate that in sql server**

Comment: This `Reference` setter is a huge anti pattern: ignoring `value` in property setters. Also, why not generate it in SQL server? A computed column looks like the perfect solution.

Comment: because there is quite possible in the future i might want to change the ST prefix to something else for the new records

Comment: Then store the prefix in another column and create a computed column that concatenates both.

Comment: @GertArnold this can be another solution. if you were me would you do it in this way or you would just create a second call to the database to update the Reference Column?

Comment: I'd go for the separate prefix column + computed column. Calling SaveChanges twice requires a TransactionScope. That's a lot of wiring for a simple task. And it's error-prone. The C# code is capable of saving different Id values in both fields, a computed column will never be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, let's see :

1. [Id] is the identity and auto-increment
2. You need to fill the column [Reference] with "ST" + [Id], always
3. You don't want to perform anything in SQL server's side
4. You are using the EF Core

The facts :

1. HasComputedColumnSql and ValueGeneratedOnAdd has nothing to do with the way you fill the column [Reference]
2. Column [Id] is non-deterministic until a row is actually written in the table
3. Column [Reference] is not Computed Column type, because it actually has real data written in it by the application, even though it always be "ST" + [Id]

Solution with the EF :

1. Add the row into the entity
2. Save the changes
3. modify the column [Reference] of the same row by using a direct assignment like this :

   student.Reference = "ST" + student.Id.ToString();
4. And again save the changes

Alternatively, you may consider to :

1. Make the [Reference] column a Computed Column in SQL Server's side
2. Or make the [Reference] property only exist in your class definition above, just without the setter. No need to keep it in the actual table, in my humble opinion.

Sorry, it may not solve your problem perfectly, because of your restrictions and limitations.

So, good luck!

Comment: Hi erlanga, thanks for your comment. The solution you suggested is the one that i ended up. I was trying to avoid the double call to the database. If i set a computed column to the database like ALTER TABLE ADD "Reference" as 'ST' + Cast([Id] varchar(50)) persited not null, is going to make a column that i wont be able to modify in the future if i decide to change the prefix for new records.

Comment: Do you want to persist the [reference] column, once the new row is added, or should all the existing records adapt to the new prefix everytime you change the prefix?